# Почему не заменяется текст в файле "replace"

Tags: python, файлы, replace

```
word = u'Karolina988'
doLoop = True

while doLoop:
    time.sleep(10)
    with open(directory, "r") as file:
        old_data = file.read()
        for line in file:
            new_data = old_data.replace('Karolina988', 'Karolina977')
            if word in line:
                with open (directory, 'w') as file:
                    bot.send_message(chatid, f"{name[0]} | Найдено: \n\n\n    {line} ")
                    time.sleep(1)
                    file.write(new_data)
                    doLoop = True
            else:
                doLoop = True
```

Код читает файл циклом, и когда находит в файле **Karolina988** отправляет уведомление в телеграм, и заменяет это слово на **Karolina977** поле чего цикл перезапускается и код опять ждет появления в файле **Karolina988**.
Но почему то ничего не меняется.

Comment: Потому что не стоит одновременно читать из файла и в него же писать

Comment: Так там же 2 with, 1 читает и закрывает файл, 2 записывает, или я что то не так сделал?

Comment: представьте, что файл это цилиндр с шариками и дном. вы сможете одновременно брать шарик сверху и ложить шарик на дно ? сомневаюсь